# php file is downloaded instead of running at the backend

Tags: server, php

I have installed Apache2 Mysql and php7 on my raspberry. When I am running my web pages under var/www/ folder the php file is downloaded instead of running at the backend and refer me to next page. What could be the problem I am facing. Please help me. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: What settings or configuration you have done?

Comment: This is not Pi specific. What you describe is the typical symptom of failing to properly install and enable PHP on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing mod-php ..
like `apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.0`